# How to open (.tif) file using System.Diagnostics

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I have problem during opening a (.tif) file it throws an exeption
"The system cannot find the file specified". Below is my code on how to open (.tif) file:

```
try
{
    ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
    p.FileName = "MSPVIEW.exe";
    p.Arguments = @"C:\New folder\sample.TIF";
    p.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.ErrorDialog = false;
    p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
    Process.Start(p);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

But when I'm going to open a (.txt) file there's no problem with it.  Below is my code on how to open (.txt) file:

```
try
{

    ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
    p.FileName = "notepad.exe";
    p.Arguments = @"C:\New folder\NewTextFile.txt";
    p.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.ErrorDialog = false;
    p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
    Process.Start(p);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Is there anybody have the same issue of opening of (.TIF) file? Or provide some solution on how to fix this?

Comment: where is mspview.exe? the location of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like either the path to `mspview.exe` or `sample.TIF` isn't valid. Can you specify the full path to `mspview.exe` and open Windows Explorer to verify the path to `sample.TIF`?

Comment: Read the question again: `But when I'm going to open a (.txt) file there's no problem with it`

Comment: Change "notepad.exe" to "MSPVIEW.exe" and this will probably be the correct answer.

Comment: A little more info: a call to notepad.exe (no path) works because it's in the base windows directory which is in the PATH environment variable.  mspview.exe is a part of Microsoft's document imaging and its path is not normally stored in the PATH area.  So you have to provide the full path to the executable.

Comment: Sorry, copied the filename from the wrong example in the question. Meant to say MSPVIEW.exe. Thanks for updating it!

Comment: I tried to edit the code which given solution from @NotMe, from this code  p.FileName = "MSPVIEW.exe" to this one  p.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MODI\12.0\MSPVIEW.exe". Then it works, Thank you very much